# Firefox Doubles Transform Values on Inline SVG Elements

Tags: css, firefox, svg, css-transforms

I'm using inline SVG with the `<use>` element like so:

```
<a href="/">
    <svg><use xlink:href="#icon-home"></use></svg>
</a>
```

On hover, I have a transform animation applied to the SVG (prefixes omitted for simplicity):

```
a:hover svg {
    transform: translateX(10px);
}
```

This works fine and dandy on every browser except Firefox. Instead of moving the SVG 10 pixels it moves 20 pixels. The same happens with a rotate value. If the rotate is set to 180 degrees Firefox will rotate the SVG 360 degrees.

Here's a Codepen: http://codepen.io/kgrote/pen/ZBKXMO

This only happens with inline SVG elements. I figure it has something to do with the SVG element having a second nested `<use>` tag.

How do I get Firefox to transform inline SVG correctly? Is this a Firefox bug that should be reported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose Firefox sees nested `<use>` tag as a second `<svg>` inside a `<svg>`.
So it goes like this:

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="#icon-home">
        <svg></svg>
    </use>
</svg>
```

First it applies `transform` to the first `svg` element and then to the second pseudo-svg.
You could use `:first-child` selector to make everything work. Here is the working example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgVGNW.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write the `<use>` tag as a `self-closing tag`. Then it will work cross browser:

```
<use xlink:href="#icon-home" />
```

Like this:

```
<a href="/">
   <svg><use xlink:href="#icon-home" /></svg>
</a>
```

See W3C spec for `<use>`

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#UseElement

See MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) `<use>`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use

Comment: What OS did you test this on? I tested on Windows 10 in Firefox 50.1.0 and i see it animate. Are you using Firefox on Mac? Thanks!

Comment: Yup, FF 49.0.1 on OSX 10.11.6.

Comment: You can report this to Mozilla Bugzilla if you want so they can fix it.. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ :)